# creating setup for c# application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have created setup for c# application with SQL Server Compact and Dot-Net Framework 4.0 as pre-requesties, I have included both SQL Server Compact 3.5 and .Net Framework 4.0 with my setup, I am trying to install SQL Server Compact and .Net Framework to get installed automatically, But it is not working.

Comment: What are you using to create your setup

Comment: simply i have created setup project in visual studio 2010

Comment: Is this an ASP.net application or a C# app? And what did you set the Specify the Install location for prerequisites in the Prerequisites Form to.  It should be Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application

Comment: C# App, yes Download Prerequesties from same location as my application.

Comment: That should work, when you build your installer it should move the packages to your setup directory and create a setup.exe file that will check for the prerequisites, install them, then run your applications MSI